# Guest Additions Install Fails For Fedora 17

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

I have currently installed fedora 17 using virtual box. I need fedora 17 for one of my courses. I needed to install guest additions for mounting a cd but I get an error

[image]

I have tried updating the kernel and the kernel headers but that does not work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming question and Fedora 17 is EOL and not supported anymore.

Comment: I read the rules and this is a legit question as the rules clearly say that you can ask questions regarding software tools. As for the version it is my choice as to which one I prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a step-by-step guide to do what you are looking for: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

You said that you installed the kernel-headers, but the tool complains that they are missing. Are they present in the expected location below /usr/src/kernels/... ?